# What does it mean "regular file" according to S_ISREG C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, file, unix

Let's consider the following 3 code lines:

```
struct stat buffer;       
status = lstat(file.c_str(), &buffer);  
bool Flag = S_ISREG(buffer.st_mode)
```

When S_ISREG() returns `true` it tells you that the file is a regular file

What does regular means exactly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is non-standard, you should check the documentation for your CRT implementation.  But it ought to mean that the name refers to a regular file, instead of a pipe, stream, symbolic link, directory or device.

Comment: what about executable file ? Is it regular also ?

Comment: We still don't know your operating system.  But typically, yes.

Comment: What about if i want to ignore executables, is there a way ?

Comment: Can't you just look at the filename extension?

Comment: hmm no, because the executables can have regular name in my case ( without extension )

Comment: I found a way to do this, by doing a logic 'And' between buffer.st_mode and S_IXUSR ...
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7):

Regular means it's not a directory, not a symlink, not a block device, and not a character device. It's just... regular. :)